# Разные варианты вызова операторов из функций-членов

Tags: c++

Есть ли разница, каким образом вызывать операторы класса из функций-членов? Например

```
(*this)(x);
this->operator()(x);
operator()(x);
```

Если да, то что лучше использовать?

Comment: разницы нет. [check](https://godbolt.org/z/CdqWHp). Следовательно, что короче и не теряет читабельности и понятности - то и лучше.

Comment: @acade спасибо, добавил в закладки сайт :)

Comment: Есть или нет разница - зависит от контекста. Придумать контексты, в которых разница есть - вполне возможно. О чем именно вопрос?

Comment: @AnT, если не составит труда, приведите пример, в котором будет иметь место разница

Answer (score 1):

Есть или нет разницы - зависит от контекста. Если задаться целью, то можно "высосать из пальца" пример, на котором будут наблюдаться некоторые различия

```
template <typename T> struct B
{
  void operator()(int) {}
};

template <typename T> struct D : B<T>
{
  void foo()
  {
    (*this)(42);          // OK
    this->operator()(42); // OK
    D::operator()(42);    // OK
    operator()(42);       // ERROR
  }
};

int main()
{
  D<int> d;
  d.foo();
}
```

В данном примере вызов `operator()(42)` не скомпилируется по причинам, которые не имеют отношения к операторам. В то же время варианты с `this` и с квалифицированным именем будут работать без проблем.